# Get text fitting into box using ColumnText

Tags: coldfusion, pdf-generation, itext

I am using iText library in a ColdFusion application for creating PDFs and the goal is to add various texts into box of certain size at certain position.

It can be perfectly done using ColumnText (details skipped):

```
<cfset directContent = writer.getDirectContent()>
<cfset ct = CreateObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText").init(directContent)>
<cfset ct.setSimpleColumn(100, 50, 400, 400, 18, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED)>
<cfset ct.setText( createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Phrase").init("#text_var#") ) >
<cfset ct.go()>
```

The problem is: long texts are cut, as expected (`go()` returns `ColumnText.NO_MORE_COLUMN`).
But I need in this case to show that text is not finished by putting for example '...' in the end (adding dots or if needed replacing one or two last symbols with '...').

Is there a simple way to achieve this? For example, after I call `go(true)` - I can see number of lines used to output the text without actually outputting it. But I need somehow to get actual text fitting into box.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a mighty old version of iText, and I don't know if what I'm about to answer is supported in the packages that were named after me.

Q1: I want to add ... in the end.
A1: if go() returns NO_MORE_COLUMN, you can get the X position of the last X position of the last line that has been written. See http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ColumnText.html#getLastX%28%29
You can get the Y position with getYLine. See http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ColumnText.html#getYLine%28%29
You could use this X and Y to add '...' at the appropriate place.

Q2: I don't want the text to be cut; I want to fit the text inside a Rectangle.
A2: that's exactly what is done in this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=163
In the method addParagraph(), text is added in simulation mode to see if it fits. If it does, the text is added for real; if it doesn't the text is added again, but using a smaller font.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! The functionality we are discussing is supported by Itext 2.1.0 provided with ColdFusion 9.  My issue is Q1 - adding '...' in the end of cutted text, not changing font size. I understood usage of getXLine and getYLine. The only problem that remains is that in this case the '...' will be added just after last symbols - that is, outside the box. And I need to replace last symbols (how much symbols - must be calculated in each case with getEffectiveStringWidth) with '...' to fit inside the box. Could you please advice something for this?

Comment: Indeed, if your text is justified, X will be the coordinate of the right border of your column. What you're asking for isn't supported. The only workaround I see, is to try simulation mode first; if the text doesn't fit, add all the lines written in simulation mode for real, except the last one by using a column with a smaller height (based on getYLine), then define a new column for the last line right under that first column, but use a smaller width, so that you have space to add the "...". That's not an elegant solution, I know... Sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you. As for proposed workaround, how do I know what text to use for the second column consisting of one shortened line?

Comment: And, once I met you personally, thank you very much for your library, which helped me a lot creating various reports in Java and ColdFusion applications.

Comment: How do you know what text to use? Well, after you perform go(true), you need to clear the column and fill it again with data. But after you perform go(false), the column has 'consumed' the data that fits the first rectangle, but still holds the data that isn't rendered. In your code, you have to keep the ct object that contains the remained of the content, but you have to change the column with setSimpleColumn() and perform go() once more on the same ct object.

Comment: Thank you, now it is clear. I tested the workaround, it works.